# percona xtrabackup considering local mysql socket as default even when host parameter is passed

Tags: mysql, percona

Trying to take a full back up of MySQL database which is in network. I have pass the host param but still it is taking backup of database in my local machine using local mysql socket at /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

When i am trying execute below command

```
xtrabackup --backup --host='192.168.10.280' --databases="sampledb" --user=dbuser --password=dbpasswd --target-dir=/mnt/s3-restore/bkup
```

I get the below output

```
200415 19:42:00  version_check Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup;host=192.168.10.280;port=3306;mysql_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' as 'dbuser'  (using password: YES) 
200415 19:42:00  version_check Connected to MySQL server
200415 19:42:00  version_check Executing a version check against the server...
200415 19:42:00  version_check Done.
200415 19:42:00 Connecting to MySQL server host: 192.168.10.280, user: sampledb, password: set, port: 3306, socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Using server version 5.6.43-log
```

Wanted to know Is it mandatory to take the backup on the same machine. If not than what param do i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Worked on this and figured out that Percona Xtrabackup will need access to '/var/lib/mysql' where the host database resides. This is read from your my.cnf and can be pulled in the actual SQL cli when you ask for @datadir.

Xtrabackup requires access to MySQL's data directory (and MySQL instance as well), so it can't be run on another server. However, it can be triggered by another server with SSH (or alternative solution).

For example:

```
ssh serverA "innobackupex --stream=xbstream /var/lib/mysql" > backup.xbstream
```